# filter list record javascript

Tags: list, javascript

I am trying to convert c# code to javascript. I am able to get list item using javascript but dont know how to filter. I am aware about caml query but cannot use it here as i need to filter same list records with different filter logic. Here is my c# code to fetch list and filter record

**c#**

```
using (var site = new SPSite(spWebUrl))
        {
            var web = site.RootWeb;
            var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("mylist");
            listItems = GetListItemsAsList(list.Items);
        }

  var topLevelNodes = listItems.Where(i => ((i["Name"] == null) ? "" : i["Name"].ToString()) == "").ToList();
```

I want equivalent linq query in javascript.

In javascript i am just able to get list data like below

```
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = context.get_web();

myList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("myList");
```

Comment: What's your different logic?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor i meant to say i will have few other filters on same list items i retrieved

Comment: I mean you want to get items where Name is null or empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CAML builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software) to generate your query and write your function like following

```
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    myList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("myList");

    var query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>''</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
    items = myList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(items);
```

You can see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993035/Building-CAML-for-querying-List-in-SharePoint) article to get CAML query from view also.

Your LINQ seems to me that your are trying to find items where `Name` is `null` or `Empty`. So in that case your CAML should look like following

```
<View><Query><Where><Or><IsNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNull><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>''</Value></Eq></Or></Where></Query></View>
```

Comment: this will give me filtered list already. What if i wanted to filter on some other things in same list then i have to again get all list with another caml query

Comment: Nope! single query can contains multiple conditions. Please pass some time with CAML building tools

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: So you have to write two CAML query. One for topLevelNodes and another one for empReportees. So build it using CAML builder

Comment: but my filter changes as per top level node. How can i build caml query for it.

Comment: It seems query does not change. Some parameters are changing. So write a function to generate CAML query by passing those parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30471/discussion-between-developmentismypassion-and-atish-dipongkor).

Comment: But when i write camlquery i always have to do context.load. So will it always go to server when i do context.load. In my c# code you see that i retrieve list items once once and then i just filter using linq queries

Comment: In your c# code, at first you are loading all items, then you are filtering.

Do the same thing in JS. Load all items at first, then filter using other js library like underscore http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Thats what i was asking. Is there anything than underscore.js i can use to filter.

Comment: another library I know is lodash https://lodash.com/

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain how i write above camlquery using underscore.js?

Comment: ok i will accept this but then there is no other way to filter data apart from using these external libraries?

Comment: Yup...... it will be manual. I mean you have to loop through items and find required items based in some conditions

Comment: i accepted . can you answer this please http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160052/filter-list-data-using-underscore-js
i would be too much thankful

Comment: You can knock me at  night over skype: du.atish@outlook.com. Now busy!